# How to add items to a class based on user input

Tags: python, class

I'm in the process of learning python and I am attempting to create a class for a football team. I am just working with different aspects of python to try and get a better understanding. I want a menu based system which will allow the user of the programme to either view all current team members or else register to join the team. Each team member will have a unique ID and when a person joins, it will simple give them the next available number. For example, Chris has the unique ID of 1, Carl has 2, so if Joe joins, he will be automatically given number three. Below is the code I currently have. Viewing card players works perfectly for me but I am struggling with adding a new player.

So my question is, how do I add a new member to the empty list I have which will store all my data and how do I implement that the next person who joins the team will be given the next available number? This is to ensure each member number is unique. Thanks in advance, eager to learn!

```
class Team(object):

    members = [] #create an empty list to store data

    def __init__(self, user_id, first, last, address):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.address = address
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@python.com'

        #instance is fully initialized so I am adding it to the list of users
        Team.members.append(self)

    def __str__(self):
        print()
        return 'Membership ID: {}\nFirst Name: {}\nSurname: {}\nLocation: {}\nEmail: {}\n'.format(self.user_id, self.first, self.last, self.address, self.email)
        print()

    @staticmethod
    def all_members():
        for user in Team.members:
            print (user)


    def add_member(Team):
        print()
        print("Welcome to the team!")
        print()
        first_name = input("What's your first name?\n")
        second_name = input("What's your surname?\n")
        address = input("Where do you live?\n")

        for x in Team:
            unique_id = unique_id =+ 1

        user[user_id] = [user_id, first_name, second_name, address]

user_1 = Team(1, 'Chris', 'Parker', 'London')
user_2 = Team(2, 'Carl', 'Lane', 'Chelsea')

def menu(object):

    continue_program = True
    while continue_program:
        print("1. View all members")
        print("2. Add user")
        print("3. Quit")
        try:
            choice = int(input("Please pick one of the above options "))

            if choice == 1:
                Team.all_members()
            elif choice == 2:
                Team.add_member(object)
            elif choice == 3:
                continue_program = False
                print()
                print("Come back soon! ")
                print()
            else:
                print("Invalid choice, please enter a number between 1-3")
                menu(object)
        except ValueError:
            print()
            print("Please try again, enter a number between 1 - 3")
        print()

 #my main program
 menu(object)
```

Comment: I don't think you want to add them to the class itself. The `members` list should be created/initialized in the `Team` class' `__init__()` method with a `self.members = []`, **not** declared as a class-level attribute the way you're doing it. That way each `Team` instance created will have its own member list instead of all instances sharing the same one. After that's done, in the `add_member()` method, you can use `self.members.append([user_id, first_name, second_name, address])` to add an item to the members of just that `Team` class instance (as opposed adding it to all of them)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things changes:

- main function operation changed
- user count field made static and automatically created with addition of new user
- temp list created to hold users

please comment if you don't understand

```
all_users = []


class Team(object):
    members = []  # create an empty list to store data
    user_id = 0

    def __init__(self, first, last, address):
        self.user_id = Team.user_id
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.address = address
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@python.com'
        Team.user_id += 1

        # instance is fully initialized so I am adding it to the list of users
        Team.members.append(self)

    def __str__(self):
        print()
        return 'Membership ID: {}\nFirst Name: {}\nSurname: {}\nLocation: {}\nEmail: {}\n'.format(self.user_id,
                                                                                                  self.first, self.last,
                                                                                                  self.address,
                                                                                                  self.email)
        print()

    @staticmethod
    def all_members():
        for user in all_users:
            print(user)

    @staticmethod
    def add_member():
        print()
        print("Welcome to the team!")
        print()
        first_name = input("What's your first name?\n")
        second_name = input("What's your surname?\n")
        address = input("Where do you live?\n")

        # for x in Team:
        #     unique_id = unique_id = + 1

        all_users.append(Team(first_name, second_name, address))


def main():
    user_1 = Team('Chris', 'Parker', 'London')
    user_2 = Team('Carl', 'Lane', 'Chelsea')

    all_users.extend([user_1, user_2])

    continue_program = True
    while continue_program:
        print("1. View all members")
        print("2. Add user")
        print("3. Quit")
        try:
            choice = int(input("Please pick one of the above options "))

            if choice == 1:
                Team.all_members()
            elif choice == 2:
                Team.add_member()
            elif choice == 3:
                continue_program = False
                print()
                print("Come back soon! ")
                print()
            else:
                print("Invalid choice, please enter a number between 1-3")
                main()
        except ValueError:
            print()
            print("Please try again, enter a number between 1 - 3")
        print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That is brilliant, I do just have one follow up question. At the moment, the membership ID is starting at 0, is there any way to force it to start at 1? Thanks again

Comment: Set user_id to any number you like during initialization

Comment: Just an afterthought to this, which is now working thank you very much! If the player Chris with User ID wanted to leave and requested that - how would I remove him from the list? and ensure the next player to join got his user id which is now available

Comment: user_id is used as class variable whose value is incremented and assigned to new object after creation. you can create a method to delete the member and create a list which contains all the deleted ids and provide id from that list if available to new user

Comment: Ah thank you! I will give that a go! Appreciate your help

Comment: i have edited the above code to include my attempt at removing a member from the team but it is not working. Can anyone advise of where I am going wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

You are so close:

```
@staticmethod
def add_member(): # belongs to the class
    print()
    print("Welcome to the team!")
    print()
    first_name = input("What's your first name?\n")
    second_name = input("What's your surname?\n")
    address = input("Where do you live?\n")

    # get the maximum id and add one
    if Team.members:
        unique_id = max(Team.members, key=lambda m: m.user_id) + 1
    else:
        unique_id = 0
    Team(unique_id , first_name, second_name, address)
```

And in the main function change on call:

```
        elif choice == 2:
            Team.add_member()
```

Comment: Thanks a million for your answer. I have implemented the changes as suggested and have received the below error message? Would you have any idea why this is?

    TypeError: max() got an unexpected keyword argument

Comment: @Jimmy what python version are you using?

Comment: @Jimmy I edited, now it should work even with python2.7